# Parsing JSON returns null object in android

Tags: java, android, json, android-asynctask

I am trying to get information using `JSON` and displaying it on the screen, the url for getting the information is given below:

> https://searchcode.com/api/codesearch_I/?q=quicksort&per_page=100

the `JSON` is given below:

```
"results": [
{
"repo": "https://github.com/robtsai/mathrocks.git",
"language": "Haskell",
"linescount": 8,
"location": "/algos_datastructures",
"name": "mathrocks",
"url": "https://searchcode.com/codesearch/view/71123349/",
"md5hash": "78fd0c4174ad9af35885b1275db3c805",
"lines": {
"1": "-- quicksort in haskell",
"2": "",
"3": "quicksort :: Ord a => [a] -> [a]",
"4": "quicksort [] = []",
"5": "quicksort (x:xs) = quicksort smallerHalf ++ [x] ++ quicksort largerHalf",
"6": "\twhere"
},
"id": 71123349,
"filename": "quicksort.hs"
},
```

Here, I am trying to get the `name` , `language` and `url` attribute. The problem is that both `name` and `language` attribute returns their respective values but `url` attribute doesn't, it returns null.

The code is given below :

**ResultsList.java**

```
public class ResultsList extends ListActivity {

private ProgressDialog pDialog;

// URL to get contacts JSON
private static String urlmain = "https://searchcode.com/api/codesearch_I/?q=";
private static final String addition="&per_page=100";

// JSON Node names
private static final String ARR_RESULTS="results";
private static final String OBJ_NAME="name";
private static final String OBJ_LANG="language";
private static final String OBJ_URL="url";

// Seach term
private static final String SEARCH_KEYWORD = "seachterm";

// contacts JSONArray
JSONArray contacts = null;

// Hashmap for ListView
ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> resultsList;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_results_list);

    resultsList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

    ListView listView=getListView();

    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            // getting values from selected ListItem
            String name = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.nameofrepo))
                    .getText().toString();
            String lang=((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.langofrepo))
                    .getText().toString();
            String urlcode = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.urlofcode))
                    .getText().toString();

            Intent intent=new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                    DisplayResults2.class);
            intent.putExtra(OBJ_NAME, name);
            intent.putExtra(OBJ_LANG,lang);
            intent.putExtra(OBJ_URL, urlcode);
            startActivity(intent);

        }
    });

    Intent intent1=getIntent();

    String search_item=intent1.getStringExtra(SEARCH_KEYWORD);

    // Calling async task to get json
    new GetContacts().execute(search_item);

}


/**
 * Async task class to get json by making HTTP call
 * */
class GetContacts extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void> {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        // Showing progress dialog
        /*pDialog = new ProgressDialog(ResultsList.this);
        pDialog.setMessage("Please wait...");
        pDialog.setCancelable(false);
        pDialog.show();*/

    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(String... search_term) {
        // Creating service handler class instance
        ServiceHandler sh = new ServiceHandler();

        // Making a request to url and getting response
        String jsonStr = sh.makeServiceCall(urlmain+
                URLEncoder.encode(search_term[0])+addition, ServiceHandler.GET);

        Log.d("search term: ", "> " + search_term[0]);
        Log.d("Response: ", "> " + jsonStr);

        if (jsonStr != null) {
            try {
                JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonStr);

                // Getting JSON Array node
                contacts = jsonObj.getJSONArray(ARR_RESULTS);

                // looping through All Contacts
                for (int i = 0; i < contacts.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject c = contacts.getJSONObject(i);

                    String name = c.getString(OBJ_NAME);
                    String lang = c.getString(OBJ_LANG);
                    String url = c.getString(OBJ_URL);


                    // tmp hashmap for single contact
                    HashMap<String, String> single_result = new HashMap<String, String>();

                    single_result.put(OBJ_NAME, name);
                    single_result.put(OBJ_LANG, lang);
                    single_result.put(OBJ_URL, url);

                    // adding contact to contact list
                    resultsList.add(single_result);
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } else {
            Log.e("ServiceHandler", "Couldn't get any data from the url");
        }

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        // Dismiss the progress dialog
        /*if (pDialog.isShowing())
            pDialog.dismiss();*/
        /**
         * Updating parsed JSON data into ListView
         * */
        ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(ResultsList.this,
                resultsList, R.layout.row_item2, new String[] { OBJ_NAME,
                OBJ_LANG,OBJ_URL }, new int[] { R.id.nameofrepo, R.id.langofrepo,
                R.id.url });


        setListAdapter(adapter);
    }

}
}
```

Here I have used an `AsyncTask` to get the `JSON` object. The results are then displayed in a `listview`.

Right after `String url = c.getString(OBJ_URL);`, I have used `Log` to get check whether the values of `url` are returned null.

```
Log.d("URL : ",url);
```

and it gave me `logcat` displayed this :

```
D/URL :: https://searchcode.com/codesearch/view/71123349/
02-23 12:52:31.950 12979-13078/com.example.shaloin.codesearch D/URL :: https://searchcode.com/codesearch/view/46026229/
02-23 12:52:31.950 12979-13078/com.example.shaloin.codesearch D/URL :: https://searchcode.com/codesearch/view/36082147/
02-23 12:52:31.950 12979-13078/com.example.shaloin.codesearch D/URL :: https://searchcode.com/codesearch/view/49572716/
02-23 12:52:31.951 12979-13078/com.example.shaloin.codesearch D/URL :: https://searchcode.com/codesearch/view/116169728/
02-23 12:52:31.951 12979-13078/com.example.shaloin.codesearch D/URL :: https://searchcode.com/codesearch/view/39926774/
02-23 12:52:31.951 12979-13078/com.example.shaloin.codesearch D/URL :: https://searchcode.com/codesearch/view/107357332/
02-23 12:52:31.951 12979-13078/com.example.shaloin.codesearch D/URL :: https://searchcode.com/codesearch/view/114502986/
02-23 12:52:31.951 12979-13078/com.example.shaloin.codesearch D/URL :: https://searchcode.com/codesearch/view/51628740/
02-23 12:52:31.951 12979-13078/com.example.shaloin.codesearch D/URL :: https://searchcode.com/codesearch/view/49574358/
02-23 12:52:31.951 12979-13078/com.example.shaloin.codesearch D/URL :: https://searchcode.com/codesearch/view/100236697/
02-23 12:52:31.951 12979-13078/com.example.shaloin.codesearch D/URL :: https://searchcode.com/codesearch/view/76176571/
02-23 12:52:31.951 12979-13078/com.example.shaloin.codesearch D/URL :: https://searchcode.com/codesearch/view/55589993/
02-23 12:52:31.951 12979-13078/com.example.shaloin.codesearch D/URL :: https://searchcode.com/codesearch/view/65881790/
02-23 12:52:31.951 12979-13078/com.example.shaloin.codesearch D/URL :: https://searchcode.com/codesearch/view/46430083/
02-23 12:52:31.951 12979-13078/com.example.shaloin.codesearch D/URL :: https://searchcode.com/codesearch/view/49572625/
02-23 12:52:31.951 12979-13078/com.example.shaloin.codesearch D/URL :: https://searchcode.com/codesearch/view/49572701/
02-23 12:52:31.951 12979-13078/com.example.shaloin.codesearch D/URL :: https://searchcode.com/codesearch/view/49574429/
02-23 12:52:31.951 12979-13078/com.example.shaloin.codesearch D/URL :: https://searchcode.com/codesearch/view/65259684/
02-23 12:52:31.951 12979-13078/com.example.shaloin.codesearch D/URL :: https://searchcode.com/codesearch/view/119281487/
```

So, I guess this means that the `url` is fetched correctly, but isn't displayed for some reasons.

Comment: Are you catching any Exception? and did you check the value of url right after `String url = c.getString(OBJ_URL);`?

Comment: are you getting `null` for `url` at `listView.setOnItemClickListener` ?

Comment: Reason for down-vote?

Comment: You dont need to set the adapter in onPostExecute[You have not added the function setListAdapter]. You can set the adapter in the activity itself and pass it the values once you receive the data

Comment: @RajasekaranM, I have a `listview` in which I display `name`, `language` and `url` and for that I have created a row. The `url` part remains empty

Comment: @ColonD, I haven't caught any exception. And yes I have checked the `url` right after `String url = c.getString(OBJ_URL);` and it return the value of the url from JSON

Comment: I have updated my question, and shown the `logcat`

Comment: @PritomMazumdar check my answer

Comment: @PritomMazumdar you are parsed data correctly and can you post your `getview()` method at here? because may be you forget to set url value to text view `urlofcode`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Code is working fine except change your `textview` `id` in `ListAdapter` in `onPostExecute` method

Like below..

change this.

```
  R.id.url
```

to

```
 R.id.urlofcode
```

here is your output

[image]

And when you click on listview will get those values..

here is Log

```
D/Output: Name =mathrocks url =Haskell urlcode =https://searchcode.com/codesearch/view/71123349/
```

Comment: Thanks a ton for the help, such a noob mistake!!

Answer (score 1):

You should play with the position.

This should work.

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        // getting values from selected ListItem
        String name = resultsList.get(position).get("name");
        String language = resultsList.get(position).get("language");
        String url = resultsList.get(position).get("url");

        Intent intent=new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                                    MainActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra(OBJ_NAME, name);
        intent.putExtra(OBJ_LANG,  language);
        intent.putExtra(OBJ_URL, url);
        startActivity(intent);

    }
});
```

**Update**

replace below code and let me know if it works.

```
 listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        // getting values from selected ListItem
        String name = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.nameofrepo))
                .getText().toString();
        String lang=((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.langofrepo))
                .getText().toString();
        String urlcode = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.url))
                .getText().toString();

        Intent intent=new Intent(getApplicationContext(),         DisplayResults2.class);
        intent.putExtra(OBJ_NAME, name);
        intent.putExtra(OBJ_LANG,lang);
        intent.putExtra(OBJ_URL, urlcode);
        startActivity(intent);

    }
});
```

Comment: Also, I have updated my question, could you please check once

Comment: Your questions says Parsing json returns null value. now, what is the problem exactly?

Comment: The `url` which I have shown above, it contains `JSON` attribute and value pairs. I am trying to display the values of `name`, `language` and `url`. The value of `name` and `language` attribute is displayed correctly, but the value of `url` is not. And I am unable to figure out why!!